# How do I draw a proper parallelogram that can be animated on iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, graphics

I'm trying to do something very simple: I need some parallelograms in my program. These are attached to other objects, all of which are `UIView`s. It's important that I be able to animate these, since the objects they are attached to can also be animated.

I've figured out how to use the transform in `UIView`/`CALayer` to do this, but the problem is that these sheared `UIView`s don't look very nice: there is no anti-aliasing of the edges.

Is there some other way to do this? I would like to use `UIView`s, since I also use them for user interaction and animation is so much easier than drawing by hand. I don't want to use OpenGL for this.

Answer (score 0):

Draw them with `UIBezierPath`.

Comment: That only works in 3.2 and higher, though. Plus, I don't see how I can animate that easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable edge antialiasing by modifying your app's `Info.plist`.

You need to add the `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` key, with Boolean `YES` as the value.  The human-friendly name in Xcode's Info editor is “Renders with edge antialiasing”.